# Can't get while loop to draw

Tags: c#, xna

I'm keeping the drawing of each object in a seperate class and calling on it then in the main Draw Class. Anyway, I need to get this loop right because I'll be modelling a lot off it.

It will draw the first time for me but after that the xCoord doesn't seem to be moving for me or else there's something else wrong with the loop. There's no syntax errors or the like, the program runs, just not how I want it to!

Any help would be much appreciated...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Draws the bottom platform (ground)
    /// </summary>
    public void DrawBottomPlatform()
    {

        int xCoord = 0;
        int yCoord = (screenHeight / 10) * 9;
        int width = screenWidth / 20;
        int height = screenHeight / 20;
        Rectangle bottomRectangle = new Rectangle(xCoord, yCoord, width, height);

        int i = 0;
        while (i <= 5)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(grassTexture, bottomRectangle, Color.White);
            xCoord += bottomRectangle.Width;
            i += 1;
        }


    }
```

Comment: This one gets another point for having an absolutely terrible title. Why would you expect a while loop to draw something? Isn't that what graphics context objects (or in this case, SpriteBatch instances) are for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never use your updated `xCoord`, the value is simply ignored once the loops starts. Instead of updating `xCoord`, move the rectangle at each iteration:

```
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 5)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(grassTexture, bottomRectangle, Color.White);
        bottomRectangle.X += bottomRectangle.Width;
        i += 1;
    }
```